# Using Global Variables inside a Nested Function in Python

Tags: python, function, nested, global

I read this code (given below) and my understanding was that, if a variable is declared global inside a function and if it is modified then it's value will change **permanently**.

```
x = 15
def change(): 
    global x 
    x = x + 5
    print("Value of x inside a function :", x) 
change() 
print("Value of x outside a function :", x)
```

**Output:**

```
Value of x inside a function : 20
Value of x outside a function : 20
```

But the code below shows a different output.
How is it that the value of x does not change inside the `print("After making change: ", x)`   and still remains 15

```
def add(): 
    x = 15
    
    def change(): 
        global x 
        x = 20
    print("Before making changes: ", x) 
    print("Making change") 
    change() 
    print("After making change: ", x) 

add() 
print("value of x",x)
```

**Output:**

```
Before making changes:  15
Making change
After making change:  15
value of x 20
```

Comment: ``add`` does not read a global ``x``, it reads the local ``x`` created by ``x = 15``. ``add`` would have to declare ``x`` as global as well.

Comment: But wouldn't the value of x change permanently when the change() function is called ?

Comment: You probably want `nonlocal`, not `global`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `add`, `x` is not a global variable; it's local to `add`. You either need to make it global as well, so that `add` and `change` are referring to the same variable

```
def add(): 
    global x
    x = 15
    
    def change(): 
        global x 
        x = 20
    print("Before making changes: ", x) 
    print("Making change") 
    change() 
    print("After making change: ", x) 

add() 
print("value of x",x)
```

or you need to declare `x` in `change` as *nonlocal*, rather than global.

```
def add(): 
    x = 15
    
    def change(): 
        nonlocal x 
        x = 20
    print("Before making changes: ", x) 
    print("Making change") 
    change() 
    print("After making change: ", x) 

add() 
print("value of x",x)
```

Comment: in the second box, the last print("value of x", x) produces a NameError: name 'x' is not defined. pretty understandable as the only x's which come into play are those from add(), i.e. local to add(), and the x from change(), which is preceded by nonlocal, thus referring to the x from add. there's no ''global'' x, thus the print from outside all functions doesn't actually have what to print after the add() function call has finished and the stack has been emptied from any x's. correct?

Comment: Yeah, looks like I incorrectly removed the original `global` declaration from `add`. Putting it back, I'm not sure there's any difference between `global` and `nonlocal` in `change`, or any reason to use `nonlocal` instead, so I'm not entirely sure what my point there was. (Probably just blanked on what I was doing in my haste to talk about `nonlocal`.)

Comment: the second option wont work, and you need to use global in both functions. with global + nonlocal you get a SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'x' found

Answer (score 2):

Inside the function `add` the variable `x` is present in the enclosing scope and not the global scope that's why your variable `x` won't change even if you use the `global` keyword.
To change this `x` you need `nonlocal` keyword which applies to the variables present in the enclosing scope.

> The `nonlocal` statement causes the listed identifiers to refer to
> previously bound variables in the nearest enclosing scope excluding
> globals.

```
# global scope
x = 0  


def add():
    # enclosing scope
    x = 15

    def change():
        nonlocal x
        x = 20

    print("Before making changes: ", x)
    print("Making change")
    change()
    print("After making change: ", x)


add()
print("value of x", x)  # this x is global variable
```

Output:

```
Before making changes:  15
Making change
After making change:  20
value of x 0
```

Answer (score 1):

when you define global `x` in change() function, nested in add() function; it defines a main global `x` variable which is different from local `x = 15` at the beginning of the add() function. when you print `x` before and after calling change(), you actually use local `x = 15` at the beginning of add() function, but final print after calling add() will use defined global `x` which defined in main scope and has the value of `20`

[more explanation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword)